# iterating over json and construction python object

Tags: python, json

I'm fetching data from remote server and for looping over the `json`

```
_server_data = json.loads(response.text)
for key in _server_data:
    value = _server_data[key]
    print(f'Data {key} and {value}')
```

right now I part of my `json` looks like this (will just post a chuck of it, it's a bit `json`)

```
Data data and [{'Primary ID': '00054X', 'EAN': '00033816049130', 'Description105': 'GBC ID Neck Chain 30 inch (760mm) Ref EB100000 [Pack 100]', 'Category': 0, 'Marketing Text': 'These GBC ID Neck Chains are chromium plated and are a stylish option to hang your ID card or visitors badge around your neck. The chains are lightweight and 30" in length.', 'Bullet 1': 'Suitable for laminated name badges and visitors cards', 'Bullet 2': 'Lightweight chain', 'Bullet 3': 'Chromium Plated', 'Bullet 4': '30" length', 'Brand Image': ['Unknown output'], 'Images': ['Unknown output', 'Unknown output', 'Unknown output'], 'QR Code Video': [], '_id': '5981e01dcde47c0854dc4afd', 'primaryId': '00054X'},...]
```

I'm not sure how to iterate over current `json` and how to construct python objects. The idea is to fetch all the data from json by `primaryId` and construct python object so I can save them in django model.

Comment: `json.loads` already creates Python object (`dict`) from the json data. Just just need to rearrange it to the structure you want.

Comment: most implementations of response objects have a json method (ie you can probably replace your response.text with `response.json()`)

Comment: @Stael yup, it's fine, I can do that, will get the same `json`, still not sure how to extract the data by `primaryId`

Comment: maybe worth looking at [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/) which if used right eliminates need for iterating. I've managed to use Flask+SQLAlchemy+Marshmallow to do one line loading to a database with nested json and one-to-many relationships

Comment: But what do you mean by "a python object"? What exactly do you want to create, and exactly what format do you need?

Comment: based on what you've printed, I would guess that you would get something like what you're looking for if you did: `for key in _server_data['data']:`

Comment: @Stael yes, oh I'm blind, need to walk a bit, can you just construct the answer so I can up vote

Comment: meh, it's barely an answer, and I doubt it's going to help someone who comes across this on google later. I did already post a `pandas` style answer, but I don't know if you use pandas, so it might be no use to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this a try, if you use pandas as all:

```
import pandas as pd
data = response.json()['data']

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df[df['Primary ID'] == '00054X']) # or whatever id you're looking for
```

if you don't use pandas that might be no help to you